# Calculating Values into Hours from a Range Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay I don't have a lot of experience with JS or JQuery, so I'm not sure where to go from here. I want the listed numbers to adjust as the slider moves. The first number should be the slider total x 30 minutes, with the total being rounded to the nearest hour. And the second number should be the slider total x 5 minutes, with the total being rounded to the nearest hour as well.

```js
var rangeSlider = function(){
    var slider = $('.range-slider'),
        range = $('.range-slider__range'),
        value = $('.range-slider__value');
      
    slider.each(function(){
  
      value.each(function(){
        var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
        $(this).html(value);
      });
  
      range.on('input', function(){
        $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
      });
    });
  };
  
  rangeSlider();
```

```css
.range-slider {
    margin: 60px 0 0 0%;
  }
  
  .range-slider {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .range-slider__range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc(100% - (73px));
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d7dcdf;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  }
  .range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background: #1abc9c;
  }
  .range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: #1abc9c;
  }
  .range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
  }
  .range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
    background: #1abc9c;
  }
  .range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: #1abc9c;
  }
  .range-slider__range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
  }
  
  .range-slider__value {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
  .range-slider__value:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: -7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    content: '';
  }
  
  ::-moz-range-track {
    background: #d7dcdf;
    border: 0;
  }
  
  input::-moz-focus-inner,
  input::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>How many quotes do you currently do a month?</h5>
                <div class="range-slider">
                    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
                    <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
                </div> 
                <br>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">  
                        <!-- This part = range value x 30 minutes rounded into hours-->
                        <p>Time Spent On Quotes NOW: <strong>5 Hours</strong></p> 
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">                                     
                        <!--This part = range value x 5 minutes rounded into hours-->
                        <p>Time Spent on Quotes with app: <strong>2 Hours</strong></p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simplify your code taking the full advantage of jQuery. 
For the computation you can use [.text( function )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function). Inside this function you can do your math operations.

A sample snippet:

```js
var rangeSlider = function () {
    var range = $('.range-slider__range');

    range.on('input', function () {
        $(this).next().html(this.value);
        var fv = +this.value;
        var nobj = $(this).closest('.range-slider').nextAll('.list-inline:first');
        nobj.find('.list-inline-item:first').find('strong').text(function (idx, txt) {
            return (fv < 13) ? (fv * 30) + ' Minutes' : Math.floor((fv * 30) / 60) + ' Hours';
        });
        nobj.find('.list-inline-item:last').find('strong').text(function (idx, txt) {
            return (fv < 13) ? (fv * 5) + ' Minutes' : Math.floor((fv * 5) / 60) + ' Hours';
        });
    }).trigger('input');
};
rangeSlider();
```

```css
.range-slider {
    margin: 60px 0 0 0%;
}

.range-slider {
    width: 100%;
}

.range-slider__range {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: calc(100% - (73px));
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #d7dcdf;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background .15s ease-in-out;
}
.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb:hover {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    background: #1abc9c;
}
.range-slider__range:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff, 0 0 0 6px #1abc9c;
}

.range-slider__value {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #2c3e50;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.range-slider__value:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: -7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid #2c3e50;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}

::-moz-range-track {
    background: #d7dcdf;
    border: 0;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h5>How many quotes do you currently do a month?</h5>
<div class="range-slider">
    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="0" max="500">
    <span class="range-slider__value">0</span>
</div>
<br>
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <!-- This part = range value x 30 minutes rounded into hours-->
        <p>Time Spent On Quotes NOW: <strong>5 Hours</strong></p>
    </li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">
        <!--This part = range value x 5 minutes rounded into hours-->
        <p>Time Spent on Quotes with app: <strong>2 Hours</strong></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Turns out my needs for this script changed slightly, and I'm not sure if it is possible to do - but is it possible to round to minutes only when the slider is at 1-12, and then anything over 12 rounds to hours?

Comment: @becca could you help me? Because the slider increases 1 by 1 may I have an example?  When slider value is 200 which value needs to be written into the list items?  Thanks so much

Comment: so the first <li></li> is 30 for every 1 on the slider. And the second list item is 5 for every 1. So If the slider is set to 1-12 then I would like the list items to be displayed in minutes, but as soon as it is displayed from 13+ then they display rounded to the nearest hour.

Comment: @becca Thanks for the reply and sorry for my delay. Snippet updated. Let me know if it is ok.

Comment: That is perfect, I appreciate your help!! One last question is if it is possible to display the first number in minutes only up until the slider is at 2, and then past that it displays in hours? Or do the two numbers both have to be displayed in minutes/hours at the same slider value?